# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre login y user en sql-server?

Tags: sql-server

No tengo muy claro de porque hay que crear dos, parece como si estuviera haciendo lo mismo dos veces,
¿en que partes se diferencia un login de un user? aparte del hecho de que para que exista el segundo se debe crear el primero con una clave

Answer (score 3):

Es muy sencillo:

"Login" garantiza la entrada a nivel de SERVIDOR. Es el usuario que se loguea a SQL Server, por así decirlo.

"User" garantiza que te puedes loguear dentro de una **única** BASE DE DATOS.

Aquí un diagrama donde se ve bastante claro:

[image: Diagrama]